# CSS module declaration doesn't work if I reference it on a specific body class

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I am new to React and Gatsby.js. I am building a blog with Gatsby and my blog has a toggle to switch between light and dark modes. I am achieving this by toggling a class on the `<body>` tag with JavaScript. Essentially, if it is light mode, the tag will be `<body>` and if it is dark mode, the tag will be `<body class="darkMode">`.

I have managed to get this to work just fine by using vanilla JavaScript to set and remove the `.darkMode` class on the `<body>` tag. However, I am having some trouble styling elements based on `body.darkMode` in my CSS modules.

In my index.module.css file, I have the following classes:

```
.section {
  color: #141414;
}

body.darkMode .section {
  color: #ebebeb;
}
```

In my index.js component, I have imported the CSS module and applied the style like this:

`<section className={indexStyles.section}></section>`

While the color property in the `.section` class does work, I notice that the `body.darkMode .section` declaration does not work when I add the `.darkMode` CSS class to the `<body>` tag. Why is this? Help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you show what styles are applied to the section when in dark mode from your dev tools?

Comment: Turns out that the `body.darkMode .section` line is also getting compiled into a long class name like `darkMode: "index-module--darkMode--3BMQh"`. Is there any way to prevent Gatsby from converting specific CSS declarations into its own random class names?

Comment: @Zlatko I managed to resolve this. See my answer in this thread. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

I figured out the solution. It turns out, Gatsby was compiling the `body.darkMode .section` into some arbitrary classnames. In reality, I wanted it to ignore `body.darkMode` but reference the local generated class name for `.section`.

I found the answer here - https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader#scope. I was able to solve my specific issue by converting the original CSS to:

```
.section {
  color: #141414;
}

body:global(.darkMode) :local(.section) {
  color: #ebebeb;
}
```

As you can see, the :global and :local selectors allow you to target your HTML correctly.

Answer (score 1):

if u want switch between Dark and Light Mode see this code

```js
 var checkbox = document.querySelector('input[name=mode]');

        checkbox.addEventListener('change', function() {
            if(this.checked) {
                trans()
                document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', 'dark')
            } else {
                trans()
                document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', 'light')
            }
        })

        let trans = () => {
            document.documentElement.classList.add('transition');
            window.setTimeout(() => {
                document.documentElement.classList.remove('transition');
            }, 1000)
        }
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:300,400,900&display=swap");
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: var(--lightBg);
  --lightBtn: #FE016C;
  --lightBg: #fff;
  --lightColor: #232323;
}

html[data-theme='dark'] {
  background: var(--lightBg);
  --lightBtn: #FFBD07;
  --lightBg: #232323;
  --lightColor: #fff;
}

h1 {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: var(--lightColor);
}

input[type=checkbox] {
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

label {
  cursor: pointer;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  width: 55px;
  height: 30px;
  background: var(--lightBtn);
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
  -moz-border-radius: 100px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  position: relative;
}

label:after {
  content: '';
  background: #fff;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 4px;
  -webkit-transition: ease-in-out 200ms;
  -moz-transition: ease-in-out 200ms;
  -ms-transition: ease-in-out 200ms;
  -o-transition: ease-in-out 200ms;
  transition: ease-in-out 200ms;
}

input:checked + label {
  background: #FFBD07;
}

input:checked + label:after {
  left: calc(100% - 5px);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(-100%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-100%);
  -o-transform: translateX(-100%);
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}

html.transition,
html.transition *,
html.transition *:before,
html.transition *:after {
  -webkit-transition: ease-in-out 200ms !important;
  -moz-transition: ease-in-out 200ms !important;
  -ms-transition: ease-in-out 200ms !important;
  -o-transition: ease-in-out 200ms !important;
  transition: ease-in-out 200ms !important;
  transition-delay: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
 <div class="container">
        <h1>Light / Dark Mode</h1>

        <input class="container_toggle" type="checkbox" id="switch" name="mode">
        <label for="switch">Toggle</label>
    </div>
```